# AES Encryption function returning null

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I am building an AES encryption app for Android. I am using the `android.util.Base64` library.

I have a class called SecondActivity.java which calls my EncryptionController.java class.

Here is how my SecondActivity looks:
The enc() is called from buttons onClick method. The issue I'm having is that the decrypt method returns an error message from the catch statement, meaning an exception is thrown. The error outputted in the Logcat refers to an illegal final block size: `javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: error:1e00007b:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_FINAL_BLOCK_LENGTH`

```
 public String enc(){


    String initVector = "RandomInitVector";
    String key = "Bar12345Bar12345Bar12345Bar12345";
    String result;


   //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


   // System.out.println(result);




    return ec.decrypt(key, initVector, ec.encrypt(key, initVector, "Hello World"));
}
```

This method calls two methods in the EncryptionController: The first is decrypt and the second is encrypt.

Here's how encrypt looks:

```
 public String encrypt(String key, String initVector, String value){




    try {


        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes("UTF-8"));


        System.out.println("Encrypted Var is: " + android.util.Base64.encode(encrypted, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT));

        return android.util.Base64.encode(encrypted, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT).toString();

    }catch(Exception e){
      return null;
    }
        //return Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted);



    }
```

And finally my decrypt method:

```
public static String decrypt(String key, String initVector, String encrypted){



try {

    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);


    byte[] original =  cipher.doFinal(android.util.Base64.decode(encrypted,0));


    return new String(original);
   // return null;



}catch(Exception e){

    e.printStackTrace();

return "this is broken ******************";
}
```

I'm not sure what is wrong but I have a feeling it has something to do with the line `byte[] original =  cipher.doFinal(android.util.Base64.decode(encrypted,0));`
 in the decrypt method. I have tried setting the encoding type to UTF-8 also, but I'm not sure that made a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem originates in the encrypt method.

java.lang.Byte.toString() returns a String object representing the unsigned Byte value; the return value of android.util.Base64.encode(encrypted, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT) is a byte array and when you call toString() on this object it would return the string representation of bytes in that array, not the actual bytes obtained from base64 encoding.
you need to change your byte array to string in a way which doesn't modify the original byte array data like below:

```
public String encrypt(String key, String initVector, String value){
    try {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println("Encrypted Var is: " + android.util.Base64.encode(encrypted, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT));

        return new String(android.util.Base64.encode(encrypted, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT));

    }catch(Exception e){
      return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! You fixed the issue!

Comment: The explanation is mostly incorrect. And the simpler solution would be to use `android.util. encodeToString()`.

Comment: @ James K Polk would you please explain which statements are incorrect so i can correct them?